# How is AggregateItemReader's itemReader is initialized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Using Spring Batch, I need to read multiple lines from a text file and pass it to the processor as `List<String>`,  I am trying to implement AggregateItemReader, I followed the below link, but I am not able to understand how this is initialized:

```
    private ItemStreamReader<AggregateItem<T>> itemReader;
```

Initialized using the setter but I am getting this error now:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class .AggregateItem
```

This is my reader:

```
 public FlatFileItemReader<String> gsmfFlatReader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<String>()
                 .name(GSMF_READER)
                 .lineMapper((line, index) -> line)
                 .build();
     }
```

https://github.com/christian-posta/batch-systems-examples/blob/master/spring-batch-example/src/main/java/org/jboss/examples/spring/batch/multiline/AggregateItemReader.java

Comment: You need to set it your self via: public void setItemReader(ItemReader<AggregateItem<T>> itemReader)

Comment: @fascynacja Initialized using the setter but i am getting this error now, updated the post.

Comment: Please put the whole stack trace

Comment: But how do you pass a `FlatFileItemReader<String>` to something which needs `ItemStreamReader<AggregateItem<T>>`? There is your problem.